# JOIN in an associative array instead of separated records

Tags: php, mysql

Table `stores`

```
id  name  date
1   foo   2011-06-15 15:10:34
2   bar   2011-07-02 16:45:18
```

Table `locations`

```
storeid  zipcode  latitude  longitude
1        90001    xxxxx     xxxxx
1        45802    xxxxx     xxxxx
2        32843    xxxxx     xxxxx
```

How can i produce an associative array that contains a key called `locations` which is an array of all locations of a store?

My current SQL ( which separate each location in a record ):

```
SELECT stores.*, locations.* FROM locations INNER JOIN stores ON stores.id = locations.storeid
```

Example of what i want:

```
array(
 [0] => array(
           "id" => 1,
           "name" => "foo",
           "locations" => array(
                           [0] => array(
                                    "zipcode" => 90001,
                                    "latitude" => -45.48513,
                                    "longitude" => 82.12432
                                   )
                           [1] => array(
                                    "zipcode" => 42802,
                                    "latitude" => -31.48513,
                                    "longitude" => 77.12432
                                   )
                          ) 
         )
)
```

and so on for other stores...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can't extract the data in one query because SQL normally works per row and hasn't got data structure like PHP arrays. You can't nest the records using JOIN. That's why you'll have to do it with with separate queries in a PHP loop. Like so:

```
$query = "SELECT s.id,s.name FROM stores AS s";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    $data[] = $row['id'];
    $data[] = $row['name'];

    $query2 = "SELECT l.zipcode, l.latitude, l.longitude FROM locations AS l WHERE storeid=".$row['id'];

    $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
        $data['locations']['zipcode'] = $row2['zipcode'];
        $data['locations']['latitude'] = $row2['latitude'];
        $data['locations']['longitude'] = $row2['longitude'];
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can grab all results with JOIN and do as follows:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM stores AS s 
LEFT JOIN locations AS l
ON s.id = l.storesid";

$result = mysql_query($query);
$data = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result )) {
    $data[$row[id]]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data[$row[id]]['name'] = $row['name'];
    $data[$row[id]]['locations'][] = array($row['zipcode'], $row['latitude'], $row['longitude']);
}
```

But this will make the main array's index to be set not sequential starting from 0 but each index will be equal to the ID of the "store" item

Comment: That's repeating stores in separated records for all the locations, exactly like my current code.

Comment: Took me some time to edit teh answer have a look wiill put more details in it.

Comment: Thanks mate, which one do you think is the fastest?

Comment: Use the second one. You have just one SQL query and the rest is computed by the PHP which takes less resources. Cheers

Comment: can you explain what is this `$data[$row[id]]` i mean the `id`